# Poisson Process clarification

Tags: expected-value, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

If we have an arrival of say passengers to a bus stop where at time $t$ the bus arrives empty and leaves immediately. Where the arrival of passengers arrive with rate $\lambda$ per hour.

$P(S_n \le t) = P(N(t) \ge n) $ where $S_n$ is the sum of arrivals.

We get that $E[N(t)] = t\lambda$.

Inter-arrival times are Exponential with mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

So we have $E[S_n] = \frac{n}{\lambda}$.

If $T$ is the total  waiting time we get $E[T] = \frac{\lambda t^2}{2}$.

Now if we have the case there $N(t) = 3$ and we want to know the expected waiting time of of the 3rd/last passenger: this wil be $E[T_3] = \frac{3t}{4}$ as follows from [Expected time of third passenger](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409033/expected-waiting-time-of-3rd-passenger)

Now, $E[S_3] = \frac{3}{\lambda}$ so the expected arrival time is the above. intuitively it seems the expected waiting time would then be $E[t-S_3] = t - \frac{3}{\lambda}$ however this is incorrect as the previous result above is the correct solution.

Herein lies my question, why is expected arrival time dependent upon $\lambda$ yet expected waiting time is not? Since total time - arrival time = waiting time.

Comment: It is due to the memoryless property of the exponential distribution - if $T$ has exponential distribution then for any $s,t>0$, $$\mathbb P(T>s+t\mid T>s) = \mathbb P(T>t). $$

Comment: @Math1000 would we then get a different result if we were to look at expected waiting time of the last passenger between time $t_1, t_2$ where $0 < t_1 < t_2$ ?

Comment: As I understand it, no. Starting at time $t_1>0$ does not affect the expected waiting time as compared to starting at time $0$.